# jQuery selector on elements added via jQuery after document load

Tags: jquery, dynamic, selector, element

jQuery selector for elements added dynamically doesn't seem to work. Put simply, I have a set of checkboxes that are added with a function. The PHP creates an add(..) entry for each row of data to be added (in this case a filename, comment and checkbox to remove it). These are added using a hard-coded templates and this works fine. I won't post the add script, but it generates entries like (amended for brevity)...

```
<tr>
  <td class="cell-file"><a href="...">afile.jpg</a></td>
  <td class="cell-comment">A comment</td>
  <td class="cell-remove a-center last"><input type="checkbox" id="...is_delete" name="...is_delete" value="1" class="removable"></td>
</tr>
```

On state change of another checkbox, I need to set all the dynamically added checkboxes to checked (and disable a button), with the following...

```
function setAddButton(arg){
if(arg){
    $('add-attachment').addClassName('disabled');
    Event.stopObserving('add-attachment', 'click');
    // Check all removable checkboxes
    $('input.removable:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
}else{
    $('add-attachment').removeClassName('disabled');
    Event.observe('add-attachment', 'click', orderAttachment.add.bind(orderAttachment));
}
}
```

The problem is that the selector `$('input.removable:checkbox')` comes back null. I've tried various forms of this selector including `$('.removable:checkbox')` & `$('input:checkbox.removable')` but nothing is selected.

Various posts say this selector should work, but it doesn't. So I am assuming this is because jQuery cannot 'see' the dynamically added elements. I've read various posts on using .live() or .on(), but this is about adding an event handler to dynamically added elements. I don't want an event handler, I just want to be able to select and set the checked attribute of the dynamically added checkboxes.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `$('input.removable:checkbox').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Also make sure you are adding unique ID's for the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not checking the box, it's selecting it! As I said, the selector comes back null. Once I can select it I can check it. And yes, each checkbox has a unique id and name. I've just shortened the HTML for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issue with this site is it's Magento with a 3rd party theme and a 3rd party extension I'm modifying. The site uses both Prototype and jQuery. [I thought Prototype was a superset of jQuery but seems not!] It's Protptype that adds the dynamic checkboxes and the standard jQuery selector doesn't work on these.

In this case, while `$('add-attachment').addClassName('disabled');` works, `$('input.removable:checkbox')` doesn't. The correct (or at least one working) syntax for Prototype is:

```
$$('input[class="removable"]').each(function(element) {
    element.checked = true;
});
```

I created a simple test to work out what was happening, presented below in case it helps anyone. One other thing I wanted was to prevent the remove checkboxes from being unchecked if the "control" checkbox was checked, while still showing and posting the state. The solution was simple but tricky to implement - what worked with Prototype alone didn't work when used with jQuery. This solution works with just Prototype and when used with jQuery too.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <div id="cbcontrol">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" onclick="forceIt(this.checked)"/>
        <label for="cb1">Check this to force-check the others</label>
      </div>
      <div id="cbhard">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" class="cb" onclick="fixIt(this)"/>
        <label for="cb2">Checkbox hard coded</label>
      </div>
      <div id="cb-template" style="display:none">
        <input type="checkbox" id="#id#" name="#name#" class="cb" onclick="fixIt(this)"/>
        <label for="#id#">Checkbox dynamic</label>
      </div>        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       // Add a checkbox dynamically using the template
       var cbtemplate = $('cb-template').innerHTML;
       var templateSyntax = /(^|.|\r|\n)(#(\w+)#)/;
       var template = new Template(cbtemplate, templateSyntax);
       data = {};
       data.id  = 'cb2';
       data.name  = 'name';
       Element.insert('cb-template', {'before':template.evaluate(data)});

       // Force checkbox states
       function forceIt(state) {    
         $$('input[class="cb"]').each(function(cb) { cb.checked = state; });
       }

       // Keep checkboxes checked
       function fixIt(cb) {
         if ($('cb1').checked) {
           cb.checked=!cb.checked;
         }
       }
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to check a checkbox you can use `prop` instead of `attr`
the property `prop` is for jquery.1.6+ if you are using an inferior version you have to use `attr`
try this:

```
$('input.removable:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not checking the box, its selecting it! As I said, the selector comes back null. Once I can select it I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `checked` in plae of `true` in `attr` like,

```
//checked in place of true
$('input.removable:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

You can use `prop` like

```
$('input.removable:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not checking the box, it's selecting it! As I said, the selector comes back null. Once I can select it I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

**your jquery version > 1.6** see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gxG7L/)

```
$('input.removable:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

**your jquery version <= 1.6**

```
$('input.removable:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

or you can use

```
$('input.removable:checkbox').attr('checked', "checked");
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not checking the box, its selecting it! As I said, the selector comes back null. Once I can select it I can check it.

Comment: @AdamLavery see the jsfiddle it works fine with ur $('input.removable:checkbox') and when i alert($('input.removable:checkbox')); i get Object object which is right